# Where can I ask a question about making a website's content distraction / clutter free for reading?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a self-answerable question wherein I want to answer how I can make a post on Medium.com distraction / clutter / bells and whistles free.

Is there a Stack Exchange website where my Q&A would be on-topic?

I am undecided whether it would be a good fit on Web Applications Stack Exchange. It does have [medium tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medium) but no question like the one I intend to post.

Comment: If you are unclear about one specific site you could ask on that sites own meta (as well). Provided you have anough reputation on its main site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a question is on-topic on [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). I asked on their meta for its acceptability [here](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4804/90094) and I got the following [response](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4805) from a moderator:

> Questions about **using** a web application as [medium](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medium) are on-topic on this
> site, just be sure that your question follow the guidelines of [How do  I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
>
> Answers that suggest the use a userscript might be well received, just
> be sure that your answer follows the guidelines of [How do I write a good answer?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)
>
> Related
>
> - [Is it OK to ask and answer my own question?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4019/88163)